# How to generate time series with correlation and autocorrelation?

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation

Is it possible to generate multiple (e.g. 3) time series, each with predefined volatility, and together with an predefined correlation matrix , plus, one of the time series has a predefined autocorrelation ? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Maybe you are seeking something along the lines of [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136291)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446093/generate-correlated-normal-random-variables). General idea is to generate normal random variables with give covariance matrix.

If Z is a vector of uncorrelated Gaussian random variables, and C is a square root of the given covariance matrix, then target variable will be mean+CZ.

To obtain C You may use Cholesky decomposition.

If You may obtain Gaussian variable with a given covariance matrix, then You may convert it to differently distributed variable using [inverse CDF method](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4404-Sigman/4404-Notes-ITM.pdf).

Important to notice, that CDF of any target vector is uniformly distributed, than You just map your CDF to a desired. Finally You have random variable from any distribution wich has given covariance matrix.